# Find the content of a discord message with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I’m making a discord bot that creates tickets to verify a customer with the ticket.

I want to be able to go into that channel and get the latest message from that channel and set it as my `ticketid` variable. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the [`TextChannel.lastMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage) property:

```js
<TextChannel>.lastMessage.content
```

---

You could also  use [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
// get latest message in channel
<TextChannel>.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then((message) => {
  console.log(message.content);
});
```

---

Alternate method that only works if you're positive the message will be cached:

```js
<TextChannel>.messages.cache.last()
```

(`TextChannel.lastMessage` is by far the easiest and most efficient, but I thought I'd list other methods just in case)

Comment: You might as well use [`TextChannel#lastMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage).

Comment: Aaaaa @Jakye you're right I totally forgot about that property 

Answer (score 0):

From the discord.js documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) you can use the last message in the channel you sent to in the [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage) class using `lastmessage.id` method to get its id and use it for your ticketid.

```
  const channelid = '222109930545610754'
  const channel = client.channelmanager.cache.fetch(channelid);
  // or const channel = client.channelmanager.cache.find(ids => ids.name === "Name");
  // if you have a specified guild. const channel guild.channelmanager.cache.find(ids => ids.name === "Name");
  var ticketnumber = channel.lastmessage.id
```

Comment: I believe they specified in there question they wanted to use the message *content*. Either way, if they only needed the ID, they could just use `TextChannel.lastMessageID`